# AngularJS directive remove class in parent element

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code to add / remove class "checked" to the radio input parent. It works perfectly when I use JQuery selector inside the directive but fails when I try to use the directive element, can someone please check my code and tell me why it is not working with element and how I can possibly add/ remove class checked to the radio input parent while using element instead of the jquery selectors? Thanks

```
    .directive('disInpDir', function() {    
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            inpflag: '='
        },        
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

           element.bind('click', function(){

                //This code will not work
                if(element.parent().hasClass("checked")){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        element.parent().removeClass("checked");
                        element.parent().addClass("checked");                                               
                    });                    
                }else{
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        element.parent().addClass("checked");
                    });
                }



                //This code works perfectly
                $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("checked");
                $('input:checked').parent().addClass("checked");


           });                      
        }
    };
    });
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="inpwrap" for="image1">
    <input type="radio" id="image1" name="radio1" value="" inpflag="imageLoaded" dis-inp-dir/>
  </div>

  <div class="inpwrap" for="image2">
    <input type="radio" id="image2" name="radio1" value="" inpflag="imageLoaded" dis-inp-dir/>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is just a guess, angularjs use jqLite to manipulate the dom, so try to wrap `element` variable like this `$(element)`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it and it shows error Uncaught ReferenceError: $element is not defined

Comment: Can you show the code. In example you use `element` not `$element`, may be plunker

Comment: Please provide a working Plunker if you are sure it will work and solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works for me in Plnkr (more or less):

http://plnkr.co/edit/vJJRYQQxH7u2bKSc27UA?p=preview

When you run this, the 'checked' class gets correctly added to the parent DIVs using only the first code you included. (I commented out the jQuery mechanism - I didn't add jQuery to this page, as a test.)

However, I think what you're trying to accomplish isn't working out because you're only capturing click events. The radio button that loses its checked attribute doesn't get a click event, only the next one does. In jQuery your selector is really broad - you're hitting every radio button, so it does what you want. But since you only trap click on the radio button that *receives* the click, it doesn't do what you want using the other pattern. `checked` gets added, but never removed.

A more Angular-ish pattern would be something like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HN7tLxkRA0jUL5GPjk5V?p=preview

```
link: function($scope) {
    $scope.checked = false;

    $scope.$watch('currentValue', function() {
      $scope.checked = ($scope.currentValue === $scope.imgNumber);
    });

    $scope.setValue = function() {
      $scope.currentValue = $scope.imgNumber;
    };
  }
```

What you see here lets Angular do all the dirty work, which is kind of the point. You can actually go a lot further than this - you could probably cut half the code out and do it all with expressions. The point is that in Angular, you really want to focus on the DATA (the model). You wire all of your behaviors and events up (controller) to things that manipulate that data, and then wire up all your DOM styles, classes, templates (view), etc. up to conditionals against that same data. And that is the point of MVC!